# How to programmatically stop multiprocessing.Pool map function

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

The [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) function is extremely useful to parallelize the processing of data;  it automatically creates chunks from the original list, and give them to different workers.

Sometimes you are scanning a list to find the only element that verifies a function (e.g., password cracking, predicate checking). In these scenario, you are not interested in getting the map of all the inputs, but only the one that verifies the check.

What is the best way to automatically parallelize these tasks?

Comment: How can you tell you're not interested in the results if you don't look at them?

Comment: For example when you want to bruteforce passwords, you know that only one password is the correct one, so when you find it, the job is done.

Comment: Just break up your input so you call map with pool_size number of items. If any of the returns matches your termination condition, stop otherwise continue with next pool_sized chunk.

Comment: Also keep in mind that would be a really slow password cracker.

Comment: @pvg: I'm not bruteforcing passwords, I'd use C. It was just to exemplify ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can just call [`terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.terminate) to abort all worker processes. You need to create a dedicated worker pool for such a task as you can't reuse it, but that is not a big problem for most scenarios.